# Upgrading laravel from 4.2 to 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have a *large* project running on Laravel 4.2 and now I would like to upgrade it to the latest release (5.4)

On the upgrading guide I can see the steps to upgrade from each release to the next one, but the 4.2 to 5.0 requires a fresh install. Hence the question: **should I install 5.4 (and fix problems) or 5.0 (running each upgrade)?**

I'm possibily using any Laravel functionality, and have organized repositories for my own custom methods; **I also need to maintain the database**. I need to upgrade because I would like to use event bradcasting with *Laravel Echo*.

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend you to install fresh 5.4 and migrate everything from your old version to the new one

Comment: @DestinatioN would you mind providing me with some benefits of doing this way instead of the other?

Comment: I upgraded from 4.2 to 5.3 myself a while ago. I think it was a good idea to skip 5.0 and so on, because for some old solutions I found very good new ones which are faster or just simpler. My code also got a full rework because at some points it got a bit messy over time.
So for me it was a good Solution

Comment: I upgraded directly to 5.4 because I was using a lot of vendors that were not supporting <5.3... it was a pain, but now I'm profiting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To those looking for an answer: **update directly to latest version, then fix changes along the way**.

Explanation:

At first I tried to upgrade version by version; it was a pain. Every single vendor had different packages for each version and that caused issues even before correcting the code. I couldn't start fixing my code because the installation requirements of the vendors were failing at a certain point of the upgrade process.

Upgrading directly to latest version requires the correction of many things, but at least those are only related to your code. In my case I had to remove `Sentry` (authentication), `Laravel OAuth`, and some others I don't remember in favor of some native packages which I hope will be maintained properly. The upside of this approach is that once you have all the packages you need installed you can work directly on your code... which is what you have to do anyway.

Comment: I have to create new project in 5.4 and then manually copy my MVC and route from 4.2 to new one by one file, bescouse there is so many structural change from 4.2 to 5.4

Comment: That's what I did. Many things can be copy-pasted in the new destination file